# Rotate camera around the character (up and down) Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, rotation

I have a script that moves the camera in third person, I got the camera to turn right and left along with the character, but I'm not able to make the camera turn around the character up and down, the camera just turns on itself !

```
public float mouseSensitivity;
public bool invertMouse;
public bool autoLockCursor;

public Transform cam;
public Transform RotationX;
float x;

void Awake () {
    Cursor.lockState = (autoLockCursor)?CursorLockMode.Locked:CursorLockMode.None;
}

void Update () {
    //Rotates the player left and right along with the camera
    this.gameObject.transform.Rotate(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * ((invertMouse) ? 1 : -1), Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * ((invertMouse) ? -1 : 1), 0);
    this.gameObject.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0 , this.gameObject.transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0);
    //rotates an example object to get its transformer and uses it to rotate the camera
    RotationX.gameObject.transform.Rotate(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * ((invertMouse) ? 1 : -1), Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * ((invertMouse) ? -1 : 1), 0);
    RotationX.gameObject.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(RotationX.gameObject.transform.localEulerAngles.x, RotationX.gameObject.transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0);
    x = RotationX.gameObject.transform.localEulerAngles.x;
    cam.gameObject.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(x , 0, 0);

    if (Cursor.lockState == CursorLockMode.None && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }
    else if (Cursor.lockState == CursorLockMode.Locked && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I studied the Unity documentation and found a solution, create an empty object and add the camera as his child, after moving on the axis I wanted only this object!

```
    this.gameObject.transform.Rotate(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * ((invertMouse) ? 1 : -1), Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * ((invertMouse) ? -1 : 1), 0);
    this.gameObject.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(this.gameObject.transform.localEulerAngles.x ,0 , 0);
```